# Getting started with T4

Tags: t4

I want to start writing T4 templates. I've heard a lot of great a things about these templates (in the Hanselminutes podcast mainly) and would like to know more. What are the best locations to look for info on T4 template writing? What do I need to get started implementing my own templates? Are there pitfalls or important things I should know?

Comment: Also, after you get past the "getting started" part, I wrote a sorta tutorial/article for writing good code generating code with T4. It covers unit testing your T4 template(not just the code it generates) and other fun stuff. It's at [my blog](http://earlz.net/view/2012/11/21/0346/how-to-unit-test-t4-code-generators)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote a little post on this with some pointers to other posts:

[Tip 3- How to get started with T4 templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/03/03/tip-3-getting-started-with-t4.aspx)

You also might want to check out David Ebbo's blog he has been doing some pretty cool things with T4.

[Oleg Sych's blog](http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/text-template-transformation-toolkit/) has a very useful intro.

Hope this helps

Alex

Comment: Unfortunately the second link is dead

Answer (score 2):

You have to have an editor. Without the syntax highlighting, figuring out which is generated code and which is generator code is an exercise in futility. Here's another editor addin that's free: http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/T4-Editor-Visual-T4-Editing.html

Answer (score 0):

I download [this](http://www.visualt4.com/).  After I watched [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/cc308634.aspx).

Comment: Both links are n longer functional (they "work" but the content is no longer what it must have once been)

Comment: Links are not T4 template related.